# WIA can not find my internal camera in windows 7

Tags: .net-2.0, wia

I am currently working on a project where I need to access a build in camera (software will run on a tablet), stream what the camera is showing, and allow the user to take a picture from the stream. I have a version of what I am trying to accomplish on my laptop with its built in camera working. The major difference is the Laptop is using windows XP the tablet is using windows 7.

Running the software on the tablet I get an exception (with some research it appears that exception is cause by no WIA device found). Is it possible that the built in Camera is not WIA compatible? The device does show in the Device Manager as an USB Camera Device, but unlike the camera on my laptop I can't access it directly. I have to use 3rd party software put in by the tablet maker to get the camera to work.

Has anyone experience similar problems? I have to believe if the tablet maker can do what I need I should be able to do something similar.

There also is the Windows Portable Device API that can access cameras, but that appears to be written in c++, without a .NET wrapper. Does anyone know of a simple tutorial of how I could get .NET to place nice with it? **EDIT**: Just tried WPD didn't list any devices either. I am beginning to thing this camera doesn't exist.

Any knowledge/ pointers to resources would be appreciated. (So far google has turned up the same few articles, no matter which way I approach the problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out my Camera was not WIA compatible. I was able to get the tablet to do what I needed it to do using directshow (actually directshow.net)

Good links if others are trying to do something similar and having similar problems
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/faq.html